# What does "Chugger" mean [in American English]?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I guys, I've come across a video on Youtube and I didn't understand what does **Chugger** mean in this conversation :

> **Guy 1**: What do you name it (the car)?
>
> **Guy 2**: I'm thinking about naming it **Chugger**, it looks like a little **Chugger**.

[image: Chugger.jpg]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked up *chug* and *chugger* in a dictionary?

Comment: In the UK it means a **Ch**arity M**ugger** .

Comment: But i didn't get it in this context .

Comment: The definitions I found are: a dull explosive sound made by or as if by a laboring engine ***2*** to move or go with or as if with chugs <a locomotive chugging along> <wearily ~ through the routine> - chug·ger n.  --Merriam Webster

Comment: I don't know, I've seen that , but doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Do you have any idea, Jim ?

Comment: Maybe it's a Slang , IDK ???!!?

Comment: that looks like an early 90’s.nissan 240.  It probably runs pretty rough judging from the picture. A chugger makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @CryptoBird: Expanding on Jim's definitions, if something "chugs along", that generally implies it moves *slowly and noisily* - sometimes, *with difficulty* (labouring), other times *ceaselessly*. In your context it seems ti be a fairly tatty car, so the implication is probably that it looks like [an old banger.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banger)

Comment: Oh, got it @Jim , Maybe that's why he name it **Chugger** (It's noisy) . You are genius Jim . Thank you so much .

Comment: Off course, if the conversants are *Australian* there might be an allusion to Aussie slang *chugging = [excessive] **drinking*** - perhaps the speaker thinks the car is old tech and/or performance-optimised, so it will "drink" a lot of fuel.

Comment: Thank you so much @FumbleFingers . You guys are **awesome** .

Comment: They are from LA btw.

Comment: That make sense too @FumbleFingers . (It **chug** a lot of fuel)

Comment: Here's a relevant usage I just found... [*It pulled hard and **chugged fuel.** My best friend from childhood called the car **chugger** on one of our summer trips while at a gas station. The name stuck.*](https://classicoldsmobile.com/forums/general-discussion/111690-how-did-you-select-your-user-name.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the U.S., though, a car with high fuel consumption is almost invariably a *[gas] guzzler*; even the [government](https://www.epa.gov/fueleconomy/gas-guzzler-tax) can't resist the alliterative appeal.

Comment: Thanks @choster , for the new word **guzzler** i'm gonna add it to my dictionary :-) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chug n., v.,  chugged, chug•ging.

> n. [countable]:
>
> - a short, dull, explosive sound:
>     *the steady chug of an engine.*
>
> v. [no object]:
>
> - to make this sound:
>     *The motor chugged.*'

- Probably a chugger, a vehicle whose engine chugs rather than run smoothly.

From: word reference.com:

> I just went through an old Disney comic strip, where Mickey sees Donald in his car, and tells him "***Hey Donald, I thought you'd blush, drivin' around in an old chugger like that".***

From: TripAdvisor:

“We came across this old chugger on one of our Perth Hills and Bickley Valley Photo Tours.”

[image]